# How to analyze only the pulses (peaks) from a signal?

Tags: matlab, vector, fft

I have a periodic signal and what I have to do is to apply the Fourier transform only on the pulses (peaks that are also formed from a number of samples, but is always the same).
I do know the number of samples that compounds a peak and the distance between them but I can't find the way to analyze only them. 
Any idea?

[image]

Comment: You should provide an example signal. In addition, what do you want to do? Extract the FFT of a peak (a part of the original vector)?

Comment: i've just put a picture of how it looks like

Comment: Check my answer, i think it is what you want.

Comment: Actually, I got an error when I try to apply it because my signal is an array and the dimensions does not exceed.

Comment: Update your question with your example code and maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your vector is:

myVector = [1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1]

And supposing that you want to extract the FFT of the peaks you can:

1. Find the peaks: using the function `findpeaks`. That will give you the peaks and the location of them
2. Apply the FFT to each sub-vector

Example

`[pks,locs] = findpeaks(myVector);`

That will give you the two peaks found in the signal: at position 6 and at position 16.

Then if you say that the with of your peaks is for example `3`, you can apply the FFT to sub-vectors

```
subVectorA = myVector(locs(1)-1, locs(1)+1);
subVectorB = myVector(locs(2)-1, locs(2)+1);
% Do the FFT to subVectorA
% Do the FFT to subVectorB
```